# Как записать значение переменной в текстовый файл на питоне?

Tags: python, переменные, запись

Программа не записывает данные в тестовый документ:

```
f = open('C:\qwert\donotedit.txt', 'r+')
c = input("Введите данные: ")
f.write(c)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: замените: `'C:\qwert\donotedit.txt'` -> `r'C:\qwert\donotedit.txt'` или используйте прямой слеш или используйте двойной обратный слеш

Answer (score 2):

У тебя не верно открыт файл. Символ обратного слеша имеет особое значение в строковых литералах. Либо добавь символ `r` перед строкой либо продублируй символы слеша.

```
file = open(r'c:\path\to\file.txt')
```

или

```
file = open('c:\\path\\to\\file.txt')
```

Подробности в документации https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals

Comment: Символ r, а не f